# horizontal bar plot: adjusting y axes label size

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

using pandas I tried to make a horizontal bar plot, but the y-axes label is cut off.
for the plot I used this data..

```
Term                                                           value
GO:0043232~intracellular non-membrane-bounded organelle    69.40887024
GO:0043228~non-membrane-bounded organelle                  68.41919153
GO:0051384~response to glucocorticoid stimulus              58.50901338
hsa04310:Wnt signaling pathway                             24.56895837
GO:0016055~Wnt receptor signaling pathway                   18.00929324
GO:0042127~regulation of cell proliferation             5.215295969
```

For y-axes label, I used "Term" column.

my code is

```
    a=list(final_table['value'])
    b=list(final_table['Term'])
    data=pd.DataFrame(a,index=b,columns=['value'])
    data[:31].plot(kind='barh',color='k',alpha=0.7)
    matplotlib.pyplot.savefig('test.png')
```

an example of horizontal bar plot looks like this : [plot](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=horizontal%20bar%20plot&newwindow=1&rls=com.microsoft:ko-KR:IE-Address&rlz=1I7ADRA_koKR486&tbm=isch&imgil=ZiRPjN006LYdKM%253A%253BoudUuaJXSUkcQM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww2.le.ac.uk%25252Foffices%25252Fld%25252Fresources%25252Fnumeracy%25252Fbar-charts&source=iu&usg=__E24ig4JGjjO2F0egdIpXEAEPZHk%3D&sa=X&ei=lJDgU7GPJpfe8AX94oGYCg&ved=0CCwQ9QEwAw&biw=1920&bih=884#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=ZiRPjN006LYdKM%253A%3BoudUuaJXSUkcQM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww2.le.ac.uk%252Foffices%252Fld%252Fimages%252Fstudy-guide-images%252Fnumeracy%252Fvar3.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww2.le.ac.uk%252Foffices%252Fld%252Fresources%252Fnumeracy%252Fbar-charts%3B500%3B345)

how can i fix it? instead of saving the image I also tried to make and write the plot in Excel file using pandas and XlsxWriter ([pandas and XlsxWriter](http://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)), but it seems XlsxWriter doesn't have the function to draw the horizontal bar plot.

Comment: It is possible to draw a [horizontal Bar Chart](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_chart_bar.html) in XlsxWriter.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
In [1]: data
Out[1]: 
                                                             value
Term                                                              
GO:0043232~intracellular non-membrane-bounded organelle  69.408870
GO:0043228~non-membrane-bounded organelle                68.419192
GO:0051384~response to glucocorticoid stimulus           58.509013
hsa04310:Wnt signaling pathway                           24.568958
GO:0016055~Wnt receptor signaling pathway                18.009293
GO:0042127~regulation of cell proliferation               5.215296


In [2]: data.plot(kind="barh", fontsize=9, figsize=(15,8)) 
In [3]: plt.yticks(range(6), 
                   ["\n".join(
                              [" ".join(i.split("~")[:-1]),
                              "\n".join(i.split("~")[-1].split(" "))])
                   for i in a.index])
```

[image: barh]

Here you gain room with :

- fontsize smaller
- larger figure
- splitting your text on different lines :

.

```
"\n".join([

" ".join(i.split("~")[:-1]), # everything before the "~" () actually [0] but since the 4th line has no "~", I put all but last to avoid redundancy.

"\n".join(i.split("~")[-1].split(" ")) # here line break every word.

])
```

Hope this helps, and don't hesitate if you have questions.